# OpenERP 7 How to null check?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

below shows my source code fragment.i need to check if null values returns from both functions.?

1.when i use fresh DB then **bpl_worker** will empty & then its return getitem error.i added **coalesce** keyword also but result same
(function 1)

2.when i use fresh DB then **bpl.company.define** table will empty and its also return error.how to check null in that type function.?
(function 2)

i tried with below code.but result same

```
if no_define_object_no[0].current_no :
```

please advice me on this.all times when i use new DB i have to face that issue

```
def _max_reg_no(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    cr.execute("""
    select coalesce(register_no, 'W00001') as reg_no
    from bpl_worker
    where id in (select max(id) from bpl_worker)
    """)
    if cr:
        res = cr.fetchone()[0]
        emp_no = str(res)
        emp_int = emp_no[1:6]
        emp_no_int = int(emp_int)
        result = 'W' + (str(emp_no_int + 1).zfill(4))
        return result

def on_change_division(self, cr, uid, ids, division_id, context=None):
    if division_id:
        division_object = self.pool.get('bpl.division.n.registration')
        division_browse = division_object.browse(cr, uid, division_id, context=context)
        result_division_id = division_browse.id
        search_condition = [
                          ('department_id', '=', result_division_id)
                          ]
        no_define_object = self.pool.get('bpl.company.define')
        no_define_id = no_define_object.search(cr, uid, search_condition, context=context)
        no_define_object_no = no_define_object.browse(cr, uid, no_define_id, context=context)
        return {'value': {'emp_no': no_define_object_no[0].current_no }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
emp_no = no_define_object_no and no_define_object_no[0].current_no or False
return {'value': {'emp_no':  emp_no}}
```

Comment: thanks Arya its worked.wat about sql query null checking.?
(my 1st function.)